# SSR React - Load Class Names Before bundle.js loads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, server-side-rendering

I am attempting to create a SSR react app with Firebase hosting and Cloud Functions. My components are using className to declare classes. My server-rendered html does not include these, it only has the **data-reactid** elements.

It is not until the bundle.js is loaded that the real **class="example-class"** is loaded.

I do not want to wait for the bundle.js to download before the classes are loaded. I'd rather not code with both

```
class="kitten-image" className="kitten-image"
```

because that seems like a waste. I have not been able to find anything that either transforms the CSS files to have the data-reactid identifiers, or to automatically include the **class="kitten-image"** on the server-side during the compile process with babel.

Overview: My server-side compiled code injects the babel compiled react components into an index.html template file, which is sent via express app on http request on **Firebase functions**. The index.html file includes hard-coded references to the webpack processed styles.css and bundle.js in the **firebase hosting** public folder.

Thus, my server-side rendered HTML should immediately be able to reference the styles.css sheet - however, the classes are not in the html until the bundle.js is loaded (which is the problem).

**Server-side rendered HTML before bundle.js loads**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Server Side Rendering - Firebase Hosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"><div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="1473597379"><h1 data-reactid="2">Hello World!</h1><p data-reactid="3"><!-- react-text: 4 -->This is a kitten: <!-- /react-text --><br data-reactid="5"/><img src="/media/kitten.jpg" alt="Kitten" data-reactid="6"/></p></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML after bundle.js loads**
*Note that class="kitten-image" has been added.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Server Side Rendering - Firebase Hosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"><div data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1"><h1 data-reactid="2">Hello World!</h1><p class="intro" data-reactid="3"><!-- react-text: 4 -->This is a kitten: <!-- /react-text --><br data-reactid="5"><img src="/media/kitten.jpg" alt="Kitten" class="kitten-image" data-reactid="6"></p></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  

</body></html>
```

**Folder Structure**

### [image: folder-structure]

**App Component Example**
*see className*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import kitten from "./kitten.jpg";
import "./App.scss";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="main">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p className="intro">This is a kitten: <br /><img src={kitten} alt="Kitten" className="kitten-image" /></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Babel Compiled Component**

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require("react");

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var kitten = "/media/kitten.jpg";

var App = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(App, _Component);

  function App() {
    _classCallCheck(this, App);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (App.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(App)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(App, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function render() {
      return _react2.default.createElement(
        "div",
        { "class": "main" },
        _react2.default.createElement(
          "h1",
          null,
          "Hello World!"
        ),
        _react2.default.createElement(
          "p",
          null,
          "This is a kitten: ",
          _react2.default.createElement("br", null),
          _react2.default.createElement("img", { src: kitten, alt: "Kitten" })
        )
      );
    }
  }]);

  return App;
}(_react.Component);

exports.default = App;
```

**Server index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../shared/App";
import express from "express";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../index.template.html', 'utf8');
const app = express();
app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  const finalHtml = index.replace('<!-- ::APP:: -->', html);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

export let ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
//app.listen(3006, () => { console.log('Listening on 3006.'); });
```

**Server index.js babel compiled**

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.ssrapp = undefined;

var _react = require("react");

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _server = require("react-dom/server");

var _App = require("../shared/App");

var _App2 = _interopRequireDefault(_App);

var _express = require("express");

var _express2 = _interopRequireDefault(_express);

var _fs = require("fs");

var fs = _interopRequireWildcard(_fs);

var _firebaseFunctions = require("firebase-functions");

var functions = _interopRequireWildcard(_firebaseFunctions);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../index.template.html', 'utf8');
var app = (0, _express2.default)();
app.get('**', function (req, res) {
  var html = (0, _server.renderToString)(_react2.default.createElement(_App2.default, null));
  var finalHtml = index.replace('<!-- ::APP:: -->', html);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(finalHtml);
});

var ssrapp = exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
//app.listen(3006, () => { console.log('Listening on 3006.'); });
```

**Webpack**

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: "public/styles.css",
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

// Webpack settings unique to browser-side script
const browserConfig = {
  entry: './src/browser/index.js',
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, "")
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractSass.extract({
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
            { 
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                ident: 'postcss',
                sourceMap: true,
                plugins: () => [
                  require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                  autoprefixer({
                    browsers: [
                      '>1%',
                      'last 4 versions',
                      'Firefox ESR',
                      'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                    ],
                    flexbox: 'no-2009',
                  }),
                ],
              },
            },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
          ],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractSass
  ],
  output: {
    filename: './public/bundle.js',
    path: __dirname
  }
}

module.exports = [browserConfig];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was initially using Babel because I was having issues compiling via webpack with the Google Cloud / firebase modules. It was trying to bundle in everything unnecessarily.

I created a separate webpack server-side configuration. This does a few things to work correctly.

1.I'm using the **"webpack-node-externals"** package which is designed to exclude node modules for backend compilation. Without this, my generated JS file was enormous. My backend has a whole node_modules folder, so it does not need these items bundled.

2.I added the false statements to **__dirname** and **__filename** - I don't know what this does or how it works, but it fixed my issue with opening and reading my html template file server-side.

3.The file-loader does not actually copy the files, with **emit: false**

4. **The Real Fix:** The .scss tester uses **css-loader/locals** This was key! It generates the correct class names on the server and places them in the components when rendering! It also does not bundle / copy and files in this configuration, since the browser side config does that.

   5. I was using the following plugin in my **.babelrc** file with the babel compile method. This breaks the image / file transfer process in webpack and must be removed from **.babelrc**

```js
  "plugins": [["transform-assets-import-to-string", {
    "baseDir": "",
    "baseUri": "/media"
  }]],
```

**Revised Webpack**

```js
const serverConfig = {
  entry: "./src/server/index.js",
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // exclude node_modules
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./functions/src/server/server.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "public/media/[name].[ext]",
          publicPath: url => url.replace(/public/, ""),
          emit: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'css-loader/locals' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```